# Add list of tuples of integers in Scala

Tags: scala, shapeless

I wish to add a list of tuples of integers i.e. given an input list of tuples of arity *k*, produce a tuple of arity *k* whose fields are sums of corresponding fields of the tuples in the list.

#### Input

```
List( (1,2,3), (2,3,-3), (1,1,1))
```

#### Output

```
(4, 6, 1)
```

I was trying to use `foldLeft`, but I am not able to get it to compile. Right now, I am using a *for* loop, but I was looking for a more concise solution.

Comment: Not an answer, but in [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) this is just `xs.suml` (if `xs` is the list here).

Comment: @TravisBrown Scalaz only supports arities up to three though. But otherwise, yes that's a good answer.

Comment: @MilesSabin: Yeah, after that you'd have to write your own monoid instances. Or have some library write them for you...

Comment: @TravisBrown yeah, someone should really write one of those ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done type safely and very concisely using [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless),

```
scala> import shapeless._, syntax.std.tuple._
import shapeless._
import syntax.std.tuple._

scala> val l = List((1, 2, 3), (2, 3, -1), (1, 1, 1))
l: List[(Int, Int, Int)] = List((1,2,3), (2,3,-1), (1,1,1))

scala> l.map(_.toList).transpose.map(_.sum)
res0: List[Int] = List(4, 6, 3)
```

Notice that unlike solutions which rely on casts, this approach is type safe, and any type errors are detected at compile time rather than at runtime,

```
scala> val l = List((1, 2, 3), (2, "foo", -1), (1, 1, 1))
l: List[(Int, Any, Int)] = List((1,2,3), (2,foo,-1), (1,1,1))

scala> l.map(_.toList).transpose.map(_.sum)
<console>:15: error: could not find implicit value for parameter num: Numeric[Any]
              l.map(_.toList).transpose.map(_.sum)
                                          ^
```

Answer (score 3):

```
scala> val tuples = List( (1,2,3), (2,3,-3), (1,1,1))
tuples: List[(Int, Int, Int)] = List((1,2,3), (2,3,-3), (1,1,1))

scala> tuples.map(t => t.productIterator.toList.map(_.asInstanceOf[Int])).transpose.map(_.sum)
res0: List[Int] = List(4, 6, 1)
```

Type information is lost when calling `productIterator` on `Tuple3` so you have to convert from `Any` back to an `Int`.

If the tuples are always going to contain the same type I would suggest using another collection such as `List`. The `Tuple` is better suited for disparate types. When you have the same types and don't lose the type information by using `productIterator` the solution is more elegant.

```
scala> val tuples = List(List(1,2,3), List(2,3,-3), List(1,1,1))
tuples: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(2, 3, -3), List(1, 1, 1))

scala> tuples.transpose.map(_.sum)
res1: List[Int] = List(4, 6, 1)
```

Comment: Agreed that it is better to use a List rather than tuples for like-typed data.  Also note that the first snippet of code isn't type-safe.

Comment: @Brian, I'm very sorry, but it appears that I somehow downvoted your answer :( I didn't mean to, but I cannot un-downvote it now, unless it is edited. If you edit it in some way, I will remove my downvote. Sorry :(

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> val list = List( (1,2,3), (2,3,-3), (1,1,1))
list: List[(Int, Int, Int)] = List((1,2,3), (2,3,-3), (1,1,1))

scala> list.foldRight( (0, 0, 0) ){ case ((a, b, c), (a1, b1, c1)) => (a + a1, b + b1, c + c1) }
res0: (Int, Int, Int) = (4,6,1)
```

Comment: This solution only works for tuple of arity 3, not for general k.

Comment: @barnesjd Okay. Reasonable.

Comment: A couple of awkwardly-formatted lines of code with no context or explanation isn't very helpful, and the fact that you're using `foldRight` while the question mentions `foldLeft` is actively confusing.